How can I create a data redaction policy in Oracle 19c that will redact data except for a row that is about the user
For a project I have to create a database that stores sensitive data and I need to implement various security measures in the database (using Oracle 19c). I have student users who can access the database and those students users are in a students table.
How can I create a data redaction policy that redacts all the columns in the students table except for the row that corresponds to the user who is querying it?
I was thinking about making a table that stored the student users' usernames and the corresponding student id's from the students table and doing something in the redaction policy expression to not redact the rows that were about the user using that table and the users username. Here's an example of a policy I tried:
DBMS_REDACT.ADD_POLICY(
        object_schema => 'HR',
        object_name => 'STUDENTS',
        column_name => NULL,
        policy_name => 'REDACT_STUDENT_DATA',
        function_type => DBMS_REDACT.FULL,
        expression => 'NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM student_mapping WHERE student_mapping.username = SYS_CONTEXT(''USERENV'', ''SESSION_USER'') AND student_mapping.student_id = students.student_id)'
    );

I'm not the best with SQL so if I'm missing any info that would help with this then lmk.

DBMS_REDACT.ADD_POLICY(
    object_schema => 'HR',
    object_name => 'STUDENTS',
    column_name => NULL, -- Redacts all columns
    policy_name => 'REDACT_STUDENT_DATA',
    function_type => DBMS_REDACT.FULL,
    expression => 'EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM student_mapping
        WHERE student_mapping.username = SYS_CONTEXT(''USERENV'', ''SESSION_USER'')
          AND student_mapping.student_id = students.student_id)'
);

